# Is it possible Oracle IAS with Java JDK 1.4.2 and client using WS-Security?

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, ws-security, jdk1.4

I need to develop a WS client and a webservice that will be deployed under an Oracle IAS 10.1.2 (Java JDK 1.4.2). Moreover, I need to access the WS using WS-Security 1.0 (request signed with certificate);

I have checked doing it with Axis2 and Rampart, but it seems there is no Java 1.4 compatibility, or at least I didn't get it work. No possibilities with Apache CXF (minimum Java 1.5).

Do you know if there is some library that is appropriate for this case and Java 1.4 compatible?

Comment: JDK 1.4.2 is long gone. I am not sure if you would be able to find any library.

Comment: Finally, I couldn't find any workaround to this issue. Luckily, I have just known there is a Tomcat using Java 1.6 that I will be able to use! So, I will use Apache CXF in this case.